# How to correctly check if a string match regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, comparison

I want to check if a string match the following pattern

Having a text contains between Two `"`and each text can be separated to another by a `;` the appending `;`is mantatory

I tried with the regular expression `/"(.*?)";?/` but can't make it work

In the code snippet below `test3` return `true` but should not match the regex

I don't know if it's my regex or the way I try my regex

```js
const regex = /"(.*?)";?/;


const test = `"hello"; "world";`;
const test2 = `"hello"; "world"`;

const test3 = `"hello; "world"`;
const test4 = `"hello"; world`;
const test5 = `"hello""world"`;

//should be true
console.log("test1",regex.test(test));
console.log("test2",regex.test(test2));

//should be false
console.log("test3",regex.test(test3));
console.log("test4",regex.test(test4));
console.log("test5",regex.test(test5));
```

Comment: You can test here: https://regex101.com/r/fsAOqR/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/^"[^"]*"(?:\s*;\s*"[^"]*")+;?$/
  ---2---
         ---------3---------
                            -4
```

... can be broken down into ...

1. `/^ ... $/`
2. `"[^"]*"`
3. `(?:\s*;\s*"[^"]*")+`
4. `;?`

... which then translates to ...

1. In between new line start and line end ...
2. match a double quote, followed by an optional sequence of characters, each character not being a double quote, followed by a double quote.
3. group `( ... )` the following match but do not capture it `(?: ... )` and force this pattern to be present at least once `(?: ... )+` ... within this group ...

   - match the sequence of an optional whitespace (WS) a semicolon and another optional WS followed by the pattern already described with/under `(2)`.
4. the entire match is allowed to end with none or exactly one semicolon.

```js
const regex = /^"[^"]*"(?:\s*;\s*"[^"]*")+;?$/;

const test1 = `"hello"; "world";`;
const test1a = `"hello" ; "world" ;"world"; "world"`;
const test2 = `"hello" ; "world"`;
const test2a = `"hello";"world" ; "world";"world"`;

const test3 = `"hello; "world"`;
const test4 = `"hello"; world`;
const test5 = `"hello""world"`;


const test6 = `"hello ; world;";"hello ;world"`;

const test6a = `"hello ;world;" "hello; world"`;
const test6b = `"hello; world"`;


//should be true
console.log("test1", regex.test(test1));
console.log("test1a", regex.test(test1a));
console.log("test2", regex.test(test2));
console.log("test2a", regex.test(test2a));

console.log("test6", regex.test(test6));

//should be false
console.log("test3", regex.test(test3));
console.log("test4", regex.test(test4));
console.log("test5", regex.test(test5));

console.log("test6a", regex.test(test6a));
console.log("test6b", regex.test(test6b));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears you want to match semi-colon separated string literals, and that means you can use

```js
const sl = String.raw`"[^"\\]*(?:\\[^][^"\\]*)*"`;
const regex = new RegExp(String.raw`^${sl}(?:\s*;\s*${sl})*;?$`);


const test = `"hello"; "world";`;
const test2 = `"hello"; "world"`;

const test3 = `"hello; "world"`;
const test4 = `"hello"; world`;
const test5 = `"hello""world"`;

//should be true
console.log("test1",regex.test(test));
console.log("test2",regex.test(test2));

//should be false
console.log("test3",regex.test(test3));
console.log("test4",regex.test(test4));
console.log("test5",regex.test(test5));
```

The regex is `^${sl}(?:\s*;\s*${sl})*;?$` matching

- `^` - start of string
- `${sl}` - the string literal pattern
- `(?:\s*;\s*${sl})*` - zero or more sequences of `;` enclosed with zero or more whitespaces and then a string literal pattern
- `;?` - an optional `;` char (add `\s*` if you need to match trailing whitespace right after)
- `$` - end of string.

The `"[^"\\]*(?:\\[^][^"\\]*)*"` pattern matches

- `"` - a `"` char
- `[^"\\]*` - zero or more chars other than `"` and `\`
- `(?:\\[^][^"\\]*)*` - zero or more occurrences of `\`, then any char, then zero or more chars other than `"` and `\`
- `"` - a `"` char.

Comment: @CharlesLavalard ... *Wiktor's* pattern is more precise/strict in its description of a string literal and the [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) approach is more adaptable/maintainable on the long run and of highest craftsmanship.

Comment: But there is one thing, a single string literal like `'"hiho"'` or even `'""'` passes the test. @CharlesLavalard ... what are the requirements for edge cases?

Answer (score 1):

It match the first two cases:

```
\"(.*)?\";?\s{1}\"(.*)?\";?
```

**Example:**

```js
const regex = /\"(.*)?\";?\s{1}\"(.*)?\";?/;


const test = `"hello"; "world";`;
const test2 = `"hello"; "world"`;

const test3 = `"hello; "world"`;
const test4 = `"hello"; world`;
const test5 = `"hello""world"`;

//should be true
console.log("test1",regex.test(test));
console.log("test2",regex.test(test2));

//should be false
console.log("test3",regex.test(test3));
console.log("test4",regex.test(test4));
console.log("test5",regex.test(test5));
```